# How to fix B10A2 error code for Ford Escape 2013?

Tags: ford, escape

I have a 2013 model Ford Escape showing an error code B10A2. It has a 1.6L engine. I know little about cars, Please help me find out what is going on and how to fix it. Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The B10A2 code is a general signal fault code. The Body Control Module receives a 5v signal from the Restraints Control Module.

To be honest this falls into the area of needing a scantool and having basic 12v skills. You may be better off having the dealer (if under warranty) or a mechanic look at this for you.

Try resetting the code first if it comes back after cycling the key than there may be a problem either in the BCM, wiring, or the RCM.

Disconnect the BCM connector C2280C and measure voltage at pin 51 key on engine off you should expect to see a 5v signal.

If you don't, disconnect the RCM connector C310B and measure resistence between pin 51 on the BCM connector C2280C and the RCM connector C310B pin 42. Spec is less than 3 ohms.

If the wire from BCM to RCM is OK. Key on engine off with the RCM connector plugged into the module backprobe pin 42 of the C310B connector and check for 5v. If there isn't 5v replace the RCM. If there is 5v and the wiring is OK replace the BCM and reprogram as necessary.

RCM Connector/BCM connector

[image]